# Trabajar con datos de un txt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb6

Con visual he creado unos formularios y estoy intentando realizarlo en html local.

Tengo unos archivos de texto como datos, creado por un programa.

```
c:\MAPPERS Archivo PV (.PV).
c:\PVS Archivo PV (.PV).
```

Ejemplo:

```
IB  081930200905300250MAD 1321ECJQZ   T07        00A200905300254AKLF  continua..
V7   94229200905300315MAD 1321ECILP   P24        00A200905300323AKLI  continua..
RGN 901130200905300650TFN 1D8CECIGZ   T13          A200905300727A     continua..
```

y x datos por linea.

Necesito que cuando se carga la pagina me lea el archivo

```
c:\MAPPERS Archivo PV (.PV).
```

y si elijo otra fecha lea el archivo

```
c:\PVS Archivo PV (.PV).
```

Lo que tengo de momento en notepad++


    
        Web report Airportservice LPA

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="cabecera">
        <img src="http://static.corp.iberia.es/atlas/img/logo_134x29.png" alt="Iberia">
        <script>
         $(function () {
             $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
             $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                 firstDay: 1
             }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
         });
         </script>
        <h1>Webreport Airport Service </h1>v.1.0
        <BR>
        <BR>
        Selecciona Fecha:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
        <BR>

        <ul>
          <li>

            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Vuelos de Llegada">Vuelos de Llegada<br>                
            </li>
            <li>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Vuelos de salida" checked>Vuelos de salida<br>
            </li>             
          </ul>
            <br>                
        </div>
        <P>Hora UTC</p>
        <div class="barra">         
        <script type="text/javascript"> function startTime(){ today=new Date(); h=today.getUTCHours(); m=today.getMinutes(); s=today.getSeconds(); m=checkTime(m); s=checkTime(s); document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s; t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);} function checkTime(i) {if (i<10) {i="0" + i;}return i;} window.onload=function(){startTime();} </script> <div id="reloj"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="marco"> 
            <div class="contenido">                    
                <br>
                <table id='miTabla' class='TablaOrden'>
                    <caption>Datos Vuelos..</caption>
                    <thead>
                    <th onclick="TablaOrden.en('miTabla',0)">CIA</th>
                    <th>VUELO</th>
                    <th>DT1</th>
                    <th>DT2</th>
                    <th onclick="TablaOrden.en('miTabla',4)">STD</th>
                    <th onclick="TablaOrden.en('miTabla',5)">ETD</th>
                    <th>Coord</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <TR><TD>VY</TD><TD>3001</TD><TD>BCN</TD><TD>TXL</TD><TD>1325</TD><TD>1400</TD><TD>alco</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:red" >F.C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:blue" >F.P&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:YELLOW" >F.U&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
                        <TR><TD>RGN</TD><TD>9011</TD><TD>MAD</TD><TD>BCN</TD><TD>0900</TD><TD>0900</TD><TD>speL</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:red" >F.C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:blue" >F.P&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:YELLOW" >F.U&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
                        <TR ><TD>DE</TD><TD>1052</TD><TD>HAJ</TD><TD>DUS</TD><TD>1200</TD><TD>1158</TD><TD>anaL</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:red" >F.C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:blue" >F.P&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:YELLOW" >F.U&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
                        <TR><TD>MT</TD><TD>1406</TD><TD>LGW</TD><TD>MAN</TD><TD>1500</TD><TD>1505</TD><TD>ctul</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:red" >F.C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:blue" >F.P&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD><a href="http://microsoft.com" style="color:YELLOW" >F.U&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>                            
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Dependiendo del `<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>` quiero que me busque en cada linea el valor fecha en formato `dd/yyyy/mm`.

En la fila lee desde el carácter 9 y son 8 caracteres.

Una vez tenga ese dato como probado, que lea de esa linea los 3 primeros caracteres y los vuelque y cree  el primer `td` y tome luego el valor pos 23 y lea los 3 caracteres y los copie en el siguiente `td`. Así varios valores.

```
<TR><TD>IB </TD><TD>MAD</TD><TD>
```

Una vez termine la primera linea, que lea las siguientes lineas y cree sus tablas y valores.

En su momento realice en visual basic.

```
Dim Fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim strCodigo As String
    Dim strLinea As String
    Fso.CopyFile "P:\mapperS.pv", "C:\gonzalez\temporal\MAPPERS.PV"
    Set ts = Fso.OpenTextFile("C:\gonzalez\temporal\MAPPERS.PV")
    strCodigo = UCase(text1.Text) & Format(DTPFecha, "ddYYYYMM")
Do While Not (ts.AtEndOfStream)
    strLinea = ts.ReadLine
    If strCodigo = Left(strLinea, Len(strCodigo)) Then
    SVALOR1 = Mid(strLinea, 1, 8)
        Dim datFecha As Date
        Dim sCodigo As String
        sCodigo = Mid(strLinea, 9, 8)
        datFecha = DateSerial(Mid(sCodigo, 3, 4), Mid(sCodigo, 7, 2), Mid(sCodigo, 1, 2))
    SVALOR3 = Mid(strLinea, 19, 4)
    SVALOR4 = Mid(strLinea, 61, 4)
    SVALOR5 = Mid(strLinea, 23, 3)
    SVALOR6 = Mid(strLinea, 42, 3)
    SVALOR7 = Mid(strLinea, 31, 5)
    SVALOR8 = Mid(strLinea, 38, 4)
    SVALOR9 = Mid(strLinea, 301, 3)
    SVALOR10 = Mid(strLinea, 985, 4)
    SVALOR11 = Mid(strLinea, 528, 2)
    SVALOR11A = Mid(strLinea, 530, 2)
    SVALOR11B = Mid(strLinea, 532, 3)
    SVALOR12 = Mid(strLinea, 536, 2)
    SVALOR12A = Mid(strLinea, 538, 2)
    SVALOR12B = Mid(strLinea, 540, 3)
    SVALOR13 = Mid(strLinea, 543, 2)
    SVALOR13A = Mid(strLinea, 545, 3)
    SVALOR13B = Mid(strLinea, 548, 3)
    SVALOR13C = Mid(strLinea, 551, 2)
    sValor14 = Mid(strLinea, 240, 3)
    SVALOR15 = Mid(strLinea, 243, 3)
    SVALOR16 = Mid(strLinea, 553, 3)
    sValor17 = Mid(strLinea, 1074, 20)
    SVALOR18 = Mid(strLinea, 1002, 15)
    SVALOR19 = Mid(strLinea, 225, 14)
    svalor20 = Mid(strLinea, 391, 2)
    SVALOR21 = Mid(strLinea, 352, 6)
    SVALOR22 = Mid(strLinea, 358, 6)
    svalor23 = Mid(strLinea, 1, 3)
    Exit Do
    End If
Loop
FichaEmbForm.lblvuelosalida.Caption = SVALOR1
FichaEmbForm.lblfecha_salida.Caption = Format(datFecha, "dd/mm/yyyy")
FichaEmbForm.lblhora_std.Caption = SVALOR3
FichaEmbForm.txthora_cetd.Text = SVALOR4
FichaEmbForm.txtdest1.Text = SVALOR5
FichaEmbForm.txtdest2.Text = SVALOR6
FichaEmbForm.txtreg.Text = SVALOR7
FichaEmbForm.txtpkn_s.Text = SVALOR8
FichaEmbForm.txtgate.Text = SVALOR9
FichaEmbForm.txtslot.Text = SVALOR10
FichaEmbForm.txtversion.Text = SVALOR11 & "/" & SVALOR11A & "/" & SVALOR11B
FichaEmbForm.txtprevision.Text = SVALOR12 & "/" & SVALOR12A & "/" & SVALOR12B
FichaEmbForm.txtfacturados.Text = SVALOR13 & "/" & SVALOR13A & "/" & SVALOR13B & "+" & SVALOR13C
FichaEmbForm.txtpax_dest1.Text = sValor14
FichaEmbForm.txtpax_dest2.Text = SVALOR15
FichaEmbForm.txttto_s.Text = SVALOR16
FichaEmbForm.txtnotaS_cic.Text = sValor17
FichaEmbForm.Textcrewinfos_cic.Text = SVALOR18
FichaEmbForm.txtosi_s.Text = SVALOR19
FichaEmbForm.Textmo_fact.Text = svalor20
FichaEmbForm.TextNombre_emb1.Text = SVALOR21
FichaEmbForm.TextNombre_emb2.Text = SVALOR22
```

No se si existe alguna forma de poder realizar esto.

Un ejemplo que he encontrado:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
<script>
  function readSingleFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML = contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Y estas trabajando con algún lenguaje del lado del servidor, por ejemplo: PHP, ASP.NET, ASP MVC u otro ?

Comment: ¿Dónde está el fichero?¿En el servidor o lo selecciona el usuario de local?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?¿En dónde te estás quedando atascado?

Comment: Hola EGR33,  lamento decirte que no está claro que es lo que estás tratando de lograr.  Ten en cuenta que cuando hablas de HTML la mayoría lo asociará  on desarrollo web y este no parece ser el caso. Además debes incluir el código que has intentado hasta el momento no simplemente pedir que alguien haga el trabajo por tí. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tengo hecho en notepad++ un html .

Comment: table id='miTabla' class='TablaOrden'>
                        <caption>Datos Vuelos..</caption>
                        <thead>
                        <th onclick="TablaOrden.en('miTabla',0)">CIA</th>
                        <th>VUELO</th>
                        <th>DT1</th>
      <th>DT2</th>
                        <th onclick="TablaOrden.en('miTabla',4)">STD</th>
                        <th onclick="TablaOrden.en('miTabla',5)">ETD</th>
                        <th>Coord</th>
      </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <TR><TD>VY</TD><TD>3001</TD><TD>BCN<

Comment: en su momento en visual

Comment: Dim Fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim strCodigo As String
    Dim strLinea As String
    Fso.CopyFile "P:\mapperS.pv", "C:\gonzalez\temporal\MAPPERS.PV"
    Set ts = Fso.OpenTextFile("C:\gonzalez\temporal\MAPPERS.PV")
    strCodigo = UCase(text1.Text) & Format(DTPFecha, "ddYYYYMM")
Do While Not (ts.AtEndOfStream)
    strLinea = ts.ReadLine
    If strCodigo = Left(strLinea, Len(strCodigo)) Then

Comment: SVALOR1 = Mid(strLinea, 1, 8)
        Dim datFecha As Date
        Dim sCodigo As String
        sCodigo = Mid(strLinea, 9, 8)
        datFecha = DateSerial(Mid(sCodigo, 3, 4), Mid(sCodigo, 7, 2), Mid(sCodigo, 1, 2))
    SVALOR3 = Mid(strLinea, 19, 4)
    SVALOR4 = Mid(strLinea, 61, 4)

Comment: svalor23 = Mid(strLinea, 1, 3)
    Exit Do
    End If
Loop
FichaEmbForm.lblvuelosalida.Caption = SVALOR1
FichaEmbForm.lblfecha_salida.Caption = Format(datFecha, "dd/mm/yyyy")
FichaEmbForm.lblhora_std.Caption = SVALOR3
FichaEmbForm.txthora_cetd.Text = SVALOR4
FichaEmbForm.txtdest1.Text = SVALOR5

Comment: me gustaría realizar algo parecido. Abrir el txt leer su info y volcar lo en la tabla

Comment: @EGR33 no se entiende muy bien el código desde los comentarios, por favor ¿podrías editar la pregunta (botón editar) y agregarlo allí? gracias.

Comment: @EGR33 ¿Existe la posibilidad de que migres estos archivos de texto a una base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar expresiones regulares.

Un ejemplo es algo como esto: /(.{3}).{5}(29200905).{6}(.{3})/

```js
$.get( "https://58ffbf16d8f8f36928e82fc965d7f39867697f38-www.googledrive.com/host/0Bxs17r_AjwPEMkpYMkpNOHJucXc/ejemplo.txt", function( data ) {
  
    data;
   var fecha = '29200905';

 //var re =  /(.{3}).{5}(29200905).{6}(.{3})/;

 var regex = new RegExp("(.{3}).{5}(" + fecha + ").{6}(.{3})");

 var myArray = data.match(regex);
 document.write(myArray[1]+"-");
 document.write(myArray[2]+"-");
 document.write(myArray[3]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si te queda alguna duda quedo atento

Respuesta a "Como busco el archivo en dependiendo del valor . Si la fecha es hoy o mayor busco c:\MAPPERS.pv y si es menor c:\ fecha (formato ddmmyy)S.SV "

```js
 var fechaInput = "2016/04/24"; // valore del input; 

 var fecha = new Date(fechaInput);
 var hoy = new Date();
 hoy.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

 var archivo = '';
 if (fecha < hoy ) { 
  var dia = fecha.getDate();
  var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
  if (mes <= 9){
     mes = '0'+mes;
  }
  var anio = fecha.getFullYear().toString().substring(2,4);
  archivo = dia+''+mes+''+anio+'S.SV';
 } else {
  archivo = 'MAPPERS.pv';
 }
 document.write(archivo);
```

Comment: Como busco el archivo en  dependiendo del valor <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>. Si la fecha es hoy o mayor busco c:\MAPPERS.pv y si es menor c:\ fecha (formato ddmmyy)S.SV .

Comment: Ver en la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que uses un framework para usar Javascript y para listas con opciones cómo: ordenar, filtrar por campos etc... mirate la [List.js](http://www.listjs.com/) 
Puedes cargar los datos en un `textarea` y con `JQuery` o `Javascript` extraer linea por linea.

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //leer cada linea, separar por campos etc...
}
```